# How to handle JWT token in Asp.Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, jwt

I have simple MVC application, with authentication template for single users. I'm using firebase for some operations and therefore I need to authenticate users differently than just through login. I have managed to use Firebase SDK for token generation, but now I wonder how should I pass the data from the controller to view?

I can think of using Model for that or Cookie. Is there any recommended way for doing this?

Comment: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/08/14/aspnet-core-21-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api

Comment: I saw these, but this is not that relevant as I'm no using an API moreover I'd like to avoid creating API just for sending a token.

Comment: No you didn't read it. also this question comes up now and then, you can search and find something on SO or Google.